# Rails open source gallery or community engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I m looking for Rails opensource community or gallery engine (or app). I already know communityengine, insoshi, eldorado. And I'm looking for something active and new - at least Rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [social_stream](https://github.com/ging/social_stream) engine. it have a good features and active development.